# Java selenium huge loop list

Tags: java, loops, selenium

I have to loop a list of 1080 customers line on our website backoffice and go through each of the customer information page and make a changement and then go back to the list of the customer. There are 55 pages of customer which displays 20 customers each page.

My program stucks each time around 7xx customers. Maybe memories are full and cannot process anymore, or the server doesn't answer anymore. I think it is something about the loop. Here is the code :

```
public class GroupCustom {

public static void main(String[] args) {



    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    //options.addArguments("--headless");
    //options.addArguments("test-type", "ignore-certificate-errors", "window-size=1200,1100");

    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();


    String login = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    String password = "xxxxx";
    int compt = 0;


    //connect to backoffice GFC and access customer list
    driver.get(url);
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(login);
    driver.findElement(By.id("passwd")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.name("submitLogin")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table group']/tbody/tr[@class=' '][2]/td[@class='text-right']/div[@class='btn-group-action']/div[@class='btn-group pull-right']/button[@class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table group']/tbody/tr[@class=' '][2]/td[@class='text-right']/div[@class='btn-group-action']/div[@class='btn-group pull-right open']/ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li[1]/a")).click();
```

//loop 55 pages of customers lines and loop 50 customers of each of these pages

```
    for(int j = 1; j<= 55;j++)
    {
        int customNumbers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@id='form-customer_group']/div[@class='panel col-lg-12']/div[@class='table-responsive-row clearfix']/table[@class='table customer_group']/tbody/tr")).size();


        for(int i = 1; i <= customNumbers; i++)
        {

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table customer_group']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[@class='text-right']/div[@class='btn-group pull-right']/a[@class='edit btn btn-default']")).click();

            Select selectOrderState = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("id_default_group")));
            selectOrderState.selectByVisibleText("Client VIP");

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='fieldset_0']/div[@class='panel-footer']/button[@id='customer_form_submit_btn']/i[@class='process-icon-save']")).click();
            compt++;
            System.out.println("le client n°" +compt+" a été changés en VIP");                                          
        }

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form-customer_group']/div[@class='panel col-lg-12']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-lg-6'][2]/ul[@class='pagination pull-right']/li/a[@class='pagination-link']/i[@class='icon-angle-right']")).click();
    }


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "L'action est terminée, "+compt+" clients ont été changés en VIP");
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

I think that the code is not optimized. If someone can help me it would be appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your big `for` with `j<=55` you can put directly  all .../tr in a list.

And after that use findelement in every element from list.

```
List<WebElement> listElems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@id='form-customer_group']/div[@class='panel col-lg-12']/div[@class='table-responsive-row clearfix']/table[@class='table customer_group']/tbody/tr"));

for(WebElement aux : listElems)
{

    aux.findElement(By.xpath("./td[@class='text-right']/div[@class='btn-group pull-right']/a[@class='edit btn btn-default']")).click();

    Select selectOrderState = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id = 'id_default_group']")));
    selectOrderState.selectByVisibleText("Client VIP");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='fieldset_0']/div[@class='panel-footer']/button[@id='customer_form_submit_btn']/i[@class='process-icon-save']")).click();
    compt++;
    System.out.println("le client n°" +compt+" a été changés en VIP");                                          
}

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form-customer_group']/div[@class='panel col-lg-12']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-lg-6'][2]/ul[@class='pagination pull-right']/li/a[@class='pagination-link']/i[@class='icon-angle-right']")).click();
```

And I recommand using only By.xpath();

Comment: Hello, thank you for this answer. I tried this which seems to me much better indeed. However when I compile, I had an exception :  org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document       I don't understand what does mean?   Thank you in advance

Comment: https://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp
Eventualy use Thread.sleep(); to wait for element to be stable. P.S.: At what line get exception?

Comment: At this line  aux.findElement(By.xpath("./td[@class='text-right']/div[@class='btn-group pull-right']/a[@class='edit btn btn-default']")).click();     It seems that the first element of the list has been processed. But the second one encouters this exception.

Comment: Put `Thread.sleep(5000)//5seconds` before it. After first element, when go back, the page is loading?

Comment: @RuoyuZhang What exactly happened with your list after changes and come back? the element which was processed disappeared from list?

Comment: Hi, no. I just entered to the customer page, change an information and come back to the customer list. It doesn't disappear.

Comment: @RuoyuZhang but html change? if yes, what exactly?